# An instance of type '' is required to access non static member ' '

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

So i understand this problem, im suppose to make my var static. I get it, but i did it and still have the same problem. Obviously im overlooking something....

Inventory.js

```js
private static var emptySlots:int;

public static function get EmptySlots():int{
    return emptySlots;
}
public static function set EmptySlots(value:int){
    emptySlots = value;
}
```

Then i call those function here....

Slot.js

```js
    if(IsEmpty()){
        ChangeSprite(slotEmpty, slotHighlight);
        Inventory.EmptySlots()++; // this is the line i try to reference 
    }
```

This is the error that gets thrown

```
Assets/Scripts/Slot.js(71,35): BCE0020: An instance of type 'Inventory' is required to access non static member 'EmptySlots'.
```

Comment: This is JavaScript? it doesn't look like any JavaScript I've ever seen. Is this some new fancy JS?

Comment: lol? im not even sure what to say to you.

Comment: I just haven't ever seen that syntax. I didn't think that you could specify private vs public properties/functions in JS. No offense was meant and I apologize if I did offend you.

Comment: @jsve It's UnityScript, which is similar to JavaScript but different. I've cleaned up the tags now.

Comment: @Chris oh ok. I was wondering if JS had suddenly gone to a classical structure without me knowing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity Script doesn't support static properties, as far as I know. Though it is old, check this discussion: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/static-getter-setter.59621/

Anyway, if it did, the correct syntax for its use would be:

```
Inventory.EmptySlots++;
```

So, I guess I'd stick with static functions on UnityScript:

```
private static var emptySlots:int;

public static function getEmptySlots():int{
    return emptySlots;
}
public static function setEmptySlots(value:int){
    emptySlots = value;
}
```

and

```
if(IsEmpty()){
    ChangeSprite(slotEmpty, slotHighlight);
    Inventory.setEmptySlots(Inventory.getEmptySlots()+1);
}
```